# How to deal with MySQL WorkBench bit(1) bug when it puts the 'b' literal before non-bit values?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert, rdbms

Let's say I have a table 'day_attribute_type'

```
id bigint(20) AI PK 
code varchar(255) 
persist_date bigint(20) 
update_date bigint(20) 
active bit(1) 
max int(11) 
min int(11) 
name varchar(255)
```

If I would add a new row into the Result Grid and press the Apply button, I would get the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `tl2`.`day_attribute_type` (`persist_date`, `update_date`, `active`, `max`, `min`, `name`) 
VALUES ('1', '2', b'1', b'12', b'12', b'text');
```

It looks like Workbench puts 'b' not only before the bit field, but also before some other fields. It's really annoying to post-edit the query and remove their buggy things.

MySQL WorkBench 8.0.16 x64, Windows 10
MYSQL Community Server 8.8.12

I've updated MySQL Workbench for a year and this nasty bug continued to appear... I've even reinstalled my Windows.

It looks like nobody is going to fix it. It is mentioned [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79604). Please, can somebody try to reproduce this bug on Linux/Max and confirm either you have it or not.

Comment: Did you found a solution or a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Still getting this issue years later on version 8.0.32 :(

Answer (score 4):

Tried this out myself (MySQL Workbench 8.0.19 on Windows) and saw the same results - agree it's pretty annoying.

As the issue hasn't been fixed in 4+ years I'd be tempted to use another MySQL GUI client for this purpose such as [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/), [ToadSQL](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-edge/) or [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/). *Credit to JW-Munich for suggesting the last one in the comments.*

Comment: every gui has its bugs and problems, so report the errors and it will be fixed if enough people cry out.(hopefully)

Comment: Would usually agree, although odd that this one hasn't been fixed yet when verified as a bug over 4 years ago and with and 4 duplicate bugs raised since. Still worth a click on the "Affects me" button on the [bug page](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79604).

Comment: that is because not enough people get  to post a bug. And some never gone to be fixed, because they don't think that is a bug. i clicked affects me, lets see if we can get more people

Comment: thanks for tips for the other clients. I actually ended up going for [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/). It's multi-platform and seems to work pretty well.

Comment: 7 years and still not fixed, I'm definitely moving to another client.