# Error: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database

Tags: mysql, sql

Executing:

```
INSERT INTO leadcenter-test.user_details_final (id, account_type, email_id, first_name, is_active, is_verified, last_name, password, phone_number) 
  VALUES ('1', 'ADMIN', 'bhavesh@gmail.com', 'Bhavesh', b'1', b'1', b'Jha', b'abcdef', b'8178436552');
```

Error:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
> the database.
>  ERROR 1064: 1064: You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; 
>  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'b'Jha', b'abcdef',
> b'8178436552')' at line 1

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: is the binary `b` before your data intentional? If not, try removing it from all your data and rerunning the query.

Comment: i'm a beginner, can you please guide me through it? @MissSkooter

Comment: first, can you please provide what your table looks like so we can better understand what your datatypes are? Like the output of `desc user_details_final`

Comment: 'id', 'int', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'account_type', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'email_id', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'first_name', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'is_active', 'bit(1)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'is_verified', 'bit(1)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'last_name', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'password', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'phone_number', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'profile_photo', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

@MissSkooter

Comment: Do you use mysql workbench? If yes, see the following question - unfortunately the workaround is manual: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56354495/how-to-deal-with-mysql-workbench-bit1-bug-when-it-puts-the-b-literal-before

Comment: not fixed, yet? any alternate way to fix that?@Shadow

Comment: Use a different mysql GUI client...

Answer (score 0):

try running this query:

```
INSERT INTO leadcenter-test.user_details_final (id, account_type, email_id, first_name, is_active, is_verified, last_name, password, phone_number) 
  VALUES ('1', 'ADMIN', 'bhavesh@gmail.com', 'Bhavesh', b'1', b'1', 'Jha', 'abcdef', '8178436552');
```

The main problem is that the `b` is added before multiple fields that are not binary. This can cause the error you are describing and as @Shadow's comment points out, there is no workaround aside from manually fixing the query every time.